# Spliting string with lookahead/lookbehind assertions for empty string match

Tags: python, regex, split

I`m trying **to split** and **to rename** some ugly looking variable names (as an example):

```
 In[1]: import re
        ugly_names = ['some-Ugly-Name', 'ugly:Case:Style', 'uglyNamedFunction']
        new_names = []

 In[2]: patt = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-z])[\-:]?(?=[A-Z])')

 In[3]: for name in ugly_names:
            loc_name = patt.split(name)
            new_names.append("_".join(s.lower() for s in loc_name))

        print(new_names)

Out[3]: ['some_ugly_name', 'ugly_case_style', 'uglynamedfunction']
```

What's wrong with my pattern? Why doesn't it match on empty string, or I'm missing something?

*p.s.*: Is it possible with Python's `regex` to split on empty strings or should I use some other functions and `.groups()`?

Comment: Python `re.split` can't split with an empty string. Use PyPi regex module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer to the question, but just an alternative way - use the [`inflection` library](http://inflection.readthedocs.io/en/latest) (have to handle `:` separately though):

```
>>> import inflection
>>>
>>> [inflection.underscore(name.replace(":", "_")) for name in ugly_names]
['some_ugly_name', 'ugly_case_style', 'ugly_named_function']
```